# How to Convert an HTML String to XML DOM

Tags: java, xml, html-parsing

I am using HTTP client 4.1.2.I want to access outlook web and get mails data.Here is the code which I have done.

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST,         
            AuthScope.ANY_PORT,AuthScope.ANY_REALM, AuthPolicy.BASIC),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(Username, password));
DefaultHttpClient Client= new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

 HttpGet get= new HttpGet(uri);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

String html=null;   
if(!entity.equals(null)){
html=EntityUtils.toString(entity,HTTP.UTF_8);
}
```

The output is HTML page in the from of String.How can I convert this into XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, well formed HTML is a form of XML, or at least that's the goal any way.

But we're talking Microsoft here...

I use [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp) to interact with HTML as if it was XML, allowing me to use things like [xPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to search the document or just access the plain old DOM.

Comment: if i can convert the HTML into Plain DOM can i get the  data

Comment: If you use Cobra (and the HTML is well formed) you already do (have the DOM) ... and yes ...

Comment: Thank you.I will try with Cobra